# Typescript/Angular2 delegate without arrow function

Tags: angular, typescript, delegates

Why typescript delegates result not equals:

```
someProperty: any;

someActionsWithItems(item: any) {
   this.someProperty = "test";
}

//if I use this. Its OK.:
this.array.forEach(item => this.someActionsWithItems(item));

// But another. It will be error because context 'this' isn't initialize (Cannot set property 'someProperty' of undefined):
this.array.forEach(this.someActionsWithItems);
```

Why???

Comment: I think you need to use bind: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript

Answer (score 2):

The difference is the arrow function. If you use the arrow function `=>`, it binds `this` to the function.

In your case

```
this.array.forEach(item => this.someActionsWithItems(item));
```

equal to

```
this.array.forEach(this.someActionsWithItems.bind(this));
```

You can refer to
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp

and 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions